Window and Leveling doesn't update to image displayed in Javascript
I have these html file that I is a simple window to load an image and to use two sliders to adjust the window and leveling of the loaded image. The image loads and the sliders adjust but the image doesn't update as the sliders move.
I am very new to js and html so it's probably something obvious
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Window and Level Adjustment</title>
    <style>
        #imageCanvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="imageCanvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
    <br>
    <label for="window">Window: </label>
    <input type="range" id="window" min="0" max="1000" value="500">
    <br>
    <label for="level">Level: </label>
    <input type="range" id="level" min="0" max="1000" value="500">

    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const windowSlider = document.getElementById('window');
        const levelSlider = document.getElementById('level');

        let originalImageData;
        let imageData;

        // Load the image
        function loadImage() {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = 'output_image.png';  // Load the uploaded image
            img.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                originalImageData = new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.data);

                // Calculate min and max intensity for dynamic slider range
                let minIntensity = 255, maxIntensity = 0;
                for (let i = 0; i < originalImageData.length; i += 4) {
                    let intensity = originalImageData[i];
                    if (intensity < minIntensity) minIntensity = intensity;
                    if (intensity > maxIntensity) maxIntensity = intensity;
                }

                console.log("Min intensity:", minIntensity);
                console.log("Max intensity:", maxIntensity);

                windowSlider.min = 0;
                windowSlider.max = maxIntensity - minIntensity;
                windowSlider.value = (windowSlider.max - windowSlider.min) / 2;

                levelSlider.min = minIntensity;
                levelSlider.max = maxIntensity;
                levelSlider.value = (levelSlider.max - levelSlider.min) / 2;

                applyWindowLevel();
            };
        }

        function applyWindowLevel() {
            const window = parseInt(windowSlider.value);
            const level = parseInt(levelSlider.value);
            const minVal = level - (window / 2);
            const maxVal = level + (window / 2);

            // Create a copy of the original image data to work on
            imageData.data.set(originalImageData);

            for (let i = 0; i < originalImageData.length; i += 4) {
                let intensity = originalImageData[i];
                let adjusted = (intensity - minVal) * (255 / (maxVal - minVal));
                adjusted = Math.min(Math.max(adjusted, 0), 255);

                imageData.data[i] = imageData.data[i + 1] = imageData.data[i + 2] = adjusted;
            }

            ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        }

        windowSlider.addEventListener('input', applyWindowLevel);
        levelSlider.addEventListener('input', applyWindowLevel);

        loadImage();

    </script>

</body>
</html>


This is output 

I'm not sure if imageData is ever initialized because when does img.onload get called? I don't think new Image() would ever invoke the load event.

I  believe img.onload is triggered when the image specified by img.src is fully loaded

But it's never getting executed. I don't see any reference to it in the Image documentation; maybe check the complete property?

This error occurs because the browser's security model (specifically, the Same-Origin Policy) prevents scripts from reading the pixel data from a canvas if it has been "tainted" by drawing an image loaded from a different origin (domain, port, or protocol). This is a security measure to prevent scripts from reading potentially sensitive data from images loaded from other domains.
By using a local python server python -m http.server and navigating to http://localhost:8000/window_level.html fixes the problem.
Additionally, If you control the image server and it allows CORS, you can set the crossOrigin attribute on the image element before setting src: img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; img.src = 'output_image.png';
Finally, if the image is hosted on a different domain, ensure that the server where the image is hosted has CORS enabled. The server should send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow your domain to access the image.
